Scroll panel performance issues VBnet
I'm trying to optimize the scroll panel by toggling the visibility of dynamically created panels inside it, but I'm struggling to get it to work.

The panels are created based on the number of steps in a machine recipe, and they are then stored in the database according to the number written on each panel. Therefore, they should always stay in their original order without switching positions.
I've tried various solutions, but since I'm a bit inexperienced, I might have made some mistakes along the way. The latest attempt involved making panels disappear, but every time a panel is hidden, the scrollbar readjusts and returns to the beginning.
Private Sub UpdatePanelVisibility()
     Dim scrollPercentage As Double = PagStep1.VerticalScroll.Value / (PagStep1.VerticalScroll.Maximum - PagStep1.ClientSize.Height)

     ' Ottieni i limiti visibili dell'area scorrevole
     Dim visibleTop As Integer = PagStep1.VerticalScroll.Value
     Dim visibleBottom As Integer = visibleTop + PagStep1.ClientSize.Height

     ' Spazio aggiuntivo prima e dopo l'area visibile (buffer)
     Dim bufferSpace As Integer = 50

     ' Ordina i pannelli per il numero nel nome
     Dim panels = PagStep1.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)().
              OrderBy(Function(pnl) Integer.Parse(pnl.Name.Replace("PanelStep", "")))

     ' Itera sui pannelli nell'ordine corretto
     For Each pnl As Panel In panels
         ' Calcola la posizione verticale del pannello
         Dim panelTop As Integer = pnl.Top
         Dim panelBottom As Integer = panelTop + pnl.Height

         ' Verifica se il pannello è visibile nell'area scrollabile con buffer
         If panelBottom > (visibleTop - bufferSpace) AndAlso panelTop < (visibleBottom + bufferSpace) Then
             ' Rendi il pannello visibile
             pnl.Visible = True
         Else
             ' Nascondi il pannello
             pnl.Visible = False
         End If
     Next

     ' Calcola la nuova posizione dello scroll in base alla percentuale memorizzata
     Dim newScrollValue As Integer = CInt(scrollPercentage * (PagStep1.VerticalScroll.Maximum - PagStep1.ClientSize.Height))

     ' Reimposta la posizione dello scroll per evitare cambiamenti involontari
     PagStep1.VerticalScroll.Value = Math.Max(0, newScrollValue)
 End Sub


Set the panel's AutoScrollMinSize property to prevent it from shrinking when you hide the controls.

You say the ScrollPanel keeps on jumping to the top - isn't that because your last line (PagStep1.VerticalScroll.Value = Math.Max(0, newScrollValue)) is setting it to 0 because newScrollValue is negative?

Have you considered replacing the base Panel with a TableLayoutPanel? You can add, remove and hide Controls. The scrollbar doesn't scroll back (if the ActiveControl doesn't change) and you can use the ScrollControlIntoView() method to move the scroll position to a specific Control when one is removed / hidden

Also consider using one outer Panel for the area you want to scroll, and set Scrollbars = True on that Panel. Then, for the content, add other Panels to the main one, with Dock = Top. This way, the main outer Panel will show scroll bars when necessary. You don't have to hide or show or calculate anything.

Thanks. I'll try these suggestions. The biggest issue is finding a way to speed things up because when there are 50 or more steps, the loading becomes really slow.

With ScrollableControls / IArrangedElements, you always have to call SuspendLayout() before you add child elements that modify the layout, then call ResumeLayout(false) at the end. Otherwise, you have cascading layout events (and related adjustments) for every new entry
